# Interaction time out in a Use case sequence diagram

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I'm looking to put an interaction time out on a use case in a sequence diagram.

For example, when the system has had no input/interaction in 60 seconds, it ends the use case.

I am not sure how to implement this, I know how alternative flows work, but time constraints elude me

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/153560/how-to-visualize-timer-functionality-in-sequence-diagram

Comment: Or maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387433/uml-sequence-diagram-message-duration